# Add 'value' from multiple radio type selections to specific row/column in mySQL using only PHP / HTML / Javascript

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, survey

I have created a database of approximately 100 words in mySQL/myPHPAdmin. I would like users of a webpage to be able to 'vote' on the words, and keep a running tally of the votes.

mySQL table is formatted as follows:

database name: paulcook_wrdp2

table name: words_initial

**id** | **word** | **rank** | **score**

INT | VARCHAR | INT | INT

The 'id' auto increments by 1, the rank and score are both initially set at 0.

I created a WordPress page which employs the following PHP script to display the words in a table with radio buttons next to them, as well as a submit button:

```
<?php

//DB Config

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "paulcook_wrdp2";

// Create Connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 
$dbname);

// Check Connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Table Header and Initialize Form

 echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Word</th> 
<th>Applicable?</th></tr><form name='selections' 
method='post'>";

// Fetch Required Fields

$sql = "SELECT id, word FROM words_initial";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// Output Data of Each Row and Radio Buttons

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr> <td>". $row["id"]. "</td><td>". 
$row["word"] . "</td><td>Y&nbsp<input type=\"radio\" 
name=\"w". $row["id"]."\" 
value=\"1\">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspN&nbsp<input 
type=\"radio\" name=\"w". $row["id"]."\"  
value=\"-1\"></td></tr>";
}

} else {
echo "0 results";
}

// Submit Button and Close Form and Table

echo "</table><br><input type='submit' name='submit' 
value='submit' style='background:black; 
cursor:pointer; border:none; display: block; margin- 
left: auto; margin-right: auto;'/></form>";
$conn->close();
```

The table looks like this:
[image: wordtable]

(I've only put in 10 words to start, it will be 100 in practice)

Some important notes:

- The table is setup so that a 'Y' selection has a 'value' of '1' and a 'N' selection has a 'value' of '-1'
- The script is setup to name each pair of buttons based on the word's id.

For example, the radio input for Y on word #4 (formal) is defined as

```
<input type="radio" name="w4" value="1">
```

and for N it is

```
<input type="radio" name="w4" value="-1">
```

(same name, negative value)

**When the user hits "submit", I want (what I need help with):**

1) for the selected radio input value to be *added* to its score - i.e. if someone votes Y on word #4, its score would become '1'. If another person votes Y, its score becomes '2'. If the next person votes N, its score would be 1 again (2+(-1)), and so on.

2) (this might be a seperate question, so please disregard if that is not kosher) I'd also like the 'rank' fields to be updated based on the scores, and the table to be sorted by 'rank' first, and by 'word' (alphabetically) second. For example if there were three words w1 / w2 / w3, with respective scores 2 / 1 / -1, the table would look like this (ids arbitrary in this ex.):

**id** | **word** | **rank** | **score**

5 | w1 | 1 | 2

2 | w2 | 2 | 1

8 | w3 | 3 | -1

I'm not sure logically how we will deal with ties yet, but any suggestions here would be appreciated.

The next part of this project is for the words to showdown in a round robin style - i.e. word with rank 1 would showdown against word with rank 10, word with rank 2 shows off against word with rank 9, and so on..

Ideally, I'd like the php to be self contained all within that one script and not call it up, but if wordpress can pass on the processing to another script hosted in the site's root, that's fine to. (I'm using insert PHP plugin for wordpress, if that is of any importance).

Thanks all, I have looked extensively for an answer to this, but I cannot find one that considers the specifics of my situation. I'm obviously new to this, so please be gentle :)

/----- EDIT -----/

Here is what is displayed when I set

```
<form action='/process.php' method='POST'>
```

With process.php being

```
<pre>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

Displayed:

```
array(2) {
["word"]=>
array(10) {
[2]=>
string(1) "1"
[3]=>
string(1) "1"
[4]=>
string(1) "1"
[5]=>
string(1) "1"
[6]=>
string(1) "1"
[7]=>
string(1) "1"
[8]=>
string(1) "1"
[9]=>
string(2) "-1"
[10]=>
string(2) "-1"
[11]=>
string(2) "-1"
}
["submit"]=>
string(6) "submit"
}
```

How can I write process.php so that instead of displaying the above, it adds the values to the 'score' column with the corresponding row ID?

Answer (score 1):

**What's wrong in your approach**

You are trying to update your database entry each time a vote has been cast. (It is same as storing your age in the database and updating it every year. Rather you can store the date of birth and calculate the age in the php script.)

**A better approach**
You should track what a user has voted (by storing it into the database). And based on the voting, you should calculate number of yes and no for a word. Then you can calculate the score in your php script.

Answer (score 1):

you have presented a clear idea conceptually, but you have no server side code.

So I will give you some pseudo code guidance

1) receive the submitted data on the server
    - use an array for the naming of your inputs

`<input type="radio" name="words[4]" value="1">
 <input type="radio" name="words[4]" value="-1">`

2) the server will process 
    eg :

```
$votes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'words');
// validate $votes
if( !is_array( $votes ) ) die( 'untimely death' );
foreach( $votes as $vote => $value ){
  // make sure it is a valid vote and value
  // if not valid SAY ASTA LA VISTA BABY
  // check here that the vote exists
  $value = (int) $value;
  if( $value !== 1 && $value !== -1 ){
     $value = 0; // 0 will have no effect
  }
  // apply the value to the database, this will be a simple SQL update
}
```

That should handle your updates

For reading in sequence SQL is your friend

```
SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY score **asc/desc** ( depending on your preference )
```

Round Robin is going to need an interface, the logic stays pretty much the same for updating and retrieving.

EDIT:

Add SQL
The SQL is going to look something like this :

NOTE THAT because of the check we did on $value, it can only be 1,-1 or 0 so we know that the value is a safe value

make sure $vote is safe : at // check here that the vote exists
// simply cast it as an int

```
$vote = (int) $vote;
"UPDATE `votes` SET score = ( score + $value ) WHERE id = $vote"
```

I would recommend you use PDO for all of your SQL transactions
See Here : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I agree With @ujjwal verma that your approach should be to store feedback and calculate totals

Comment: Thank you @ujjwal and Craig Bezuidenhout for your tips. The user approach is likely better, but I am trying to minimize the code overhead as I have very little skill. That said, I am not sure it is necessary - this is to facilitate a workshop, and attendees will be asked to go onto the webpage and fill out the survey immediately (they will have 15 minutes, at which time they will be asked to submit, and then we will proceed to round 2). Tracking who voted what is not important.

Comment: Craig, for your code, would that be inserted in the same PHP script I already have? What about the SQL bit? Would I have to initialize that manually? In your PHP, how would it know what vote to attribute to what row ID? Would this add it, or simply change the value? Thanks again!

Comment: I am seeing in phpMyAdmin that I can setup triggers - so I assume that I can set it up so that AFTER UPDATE, I can have it run that  Order By SQL command. ... Now to see how I can actually have it update!

Comment: I've tried the above, and unfortunately it does not work. The 'process' page just hangs and never loads. What I did was create a PHP code snippet with the 'Insert PHP' plugin, and placed it on a page (I tried to simply upload it by FTP but it says 'Page not found'. I then added 'action=/inded.php/process-votes' to the form attributes. What a bummer.

Comment: Hey! @Craig Bezuidenhout - can you have a look at my edit above which explains the POST output on submission? Hoping someone can let me know what the php would be to add the values to my db.

Comment: in you inputs name="words[4]"  the "4" is the DB id
Therefore : $vote is the Id in the PHP foreach loop

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Craig - unfortunately it seems I am more inept than you thought! Hah. Do the extra lines you provided go into my process PHP? i.e. Replace this in your script "// apply the value to the database,...." Within that script, would I have to connect to the DB as I do in the first script that populates the table?